# Stack Overflow Teams data dump date format

Tags: support

What is the date format used in the [Stack Overflow Teams data dump](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)? Ex.

```json
},{  
 "name": ...,  
 "creationDate": "\/Date(1448528495027)\/",  
 "memberCount": ...,  
 "websiteUrl": ...,
...
```

Every number is in the one trillions. The ones I've seen anyways. I can't see an obvious year-month-date combo in there. Year woulda been 2015 or 2016 based on [private beta signup post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow). I thought about seconds since UNIX epoch but that's billions. Wolfram Alpha was no help, it tried to tell me about the nutritional value of [palm fruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_palm) and trillions of shares of a stock with ticker symbol DATE.

A full schema would be great if anyone has one. Just the date info would be enough though.

(Maybe I shoulda asked this on MSO and not MSE? But I don't have five rep there. Crazy edge case. Sorry!)

Comment: I assume like Unix time but milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: It *is* in milliseconds, so you can either truncate the last three digits or just specify it that way when converting to your own format. However, given that is returns the Date() function around it, I'd venture a guess that the dump is incorrectly returning that number, and that it's actually supposed to return the formatted date we'd normally see, but it's just not getting run due to a coding error.

Comment: MILLIseconds. Of _course_. How could I have gotten so close and still missed it?

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing there is the JSON encoding for a .NET DateTime struct when those structs are serialized by either the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

From that documentation:

> Date object, represented in JSON as "\/Date(number of ticks)\/". The number of ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates the number of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.

Here is a small LinqPad demo that shows the same result:

```json
void Main()
{
    var ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Team));
    var obj = new Team { Created = DateTime.UtcNow };
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       ds.WriteObject(ms, obj);
       Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()).Dump();
    }

}

[DataContract(Name="Team")]
class Team 
{
   [DataMember(Name="creationDate")]
   public DateTime Created {get;set;}
}
```

This will output:

> ```json
> {"creationDate":"\/Date(1492438726677)\/"}
> ```

I have a small [Glitch project](https://se-team.glitch.me/) that uses the Team data dump.